# Shift value to some point in binary number

Tags: microcontroller, avr, microprocessor, assembly, binary

I wonder if it is possible to do the following.
For instance, I have a number 00001110. I am shifting it left. -> 00011100....
But the question is if it possible to start setting value in carry flag not from the seventh bit but from the sixth. There is a command - ROL it shifts a seventh bit into C flag, and than stores this value in the zero bit.
But I need to do like this ,but don't do anything with seventh bit, and store sixth bit in C flag and than also store it in zero bit. I mean when the value is 01110000 the next value should be 01100001.
Is it possible to do like this. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: are you writing the code in C? or assembly?

Comment: assembly, I have specified this as tag and ROL is asm commadn

Comment: Does the value of bit 7 matter?  Must it be always 0 or can it be either 1 or 0 without affecting your desired outcome?

Comment: It should be always zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIC assembler code.  Value is in a register named "Register"

```
  clrc  ;clear C bit    
  btfsc  Register,6  ;is bit 6 Hi?    
    setc  ;set C if bit 6 is set
  rlf Register,F  ;rotate left through C
  bcf Register,7  ;clear bit 7
```

I know there is a better way to do this but this should get you started.

Comment: I quess it should work, but unfortuanatly I am using AVR

Comment: That's fine. Just use the AVR op-codes to duplicate that functionality.

Comment: I need one command and it will be complete, maybe you know this. How can I check only one bit in avr, I need to check seventh bit

Comment: So you basically want bits to get moved like this..? B7 stays the same (0 in your example), bits 6-1 get the previous values of bits 5-0, then bit 0 gets the previous value of bit 6?

Comment: Do you actually care about the value of C at the end, or only care about the value in the Register?

Comment: You can check a single bit in AVR with the a BST followed by a BRTC, but I think there may be a more efficient way to get what you want- see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If all you really want is to rotate bits 5-0 to bits 6-1, and then put the original value of bit 6 into bit 0, then the following code will deterministically complete in exactly 4 cycles and will occupy 8 words of program memory.

```
bst r16,6 ; Store bit 6 of in T Flag
lsl r16   ; logical shift left by one bit. bit 0 gets 0. 
bld r16,0 ; Load T into bit 0 
cbr r16, $7F ; clear bit 7
```

Here is what is happening at each step...

[image]

This code operates on register R16, but can be modified to work with registers R16-31. This will not work on registers below R16 because of the limited range of the cbr at the end that clears bit 7.

If you require that the code work uniformly on any register (including R0-15), then you can clear bit 7 with a left-shift/right-shift combination that takes an additional cycle and 2 additional words of memory...

```
bst r1,6 ; Store bit 6 of in T Flag
lsl r1   ; logical shift left by one bit. bit 0 gets 0. 
bld r1,0 ; Load T into bit 0 
lsl r1   ; logical shift left. 
lsr r1   ; logical shift right. bit 7 gets 0.
```

Here is what is happening...

[image]

This code operates on register R1, but can be modified to work on any register.

Finally, if you need the carry bit set according to the original value of bit 6 (it was not just a side effect), you could use the following (even longer) code...

```
bst r1,6 ; Store bit 6 of in T Flag
lsl r1   ; logical shift left by one bit. bit 0 gets 0. 
bld r1,0 ; Load T into bit 0 
lsl r1   ; logical shift left. 
bld r1,0 ; Load T into bit 0 
lsr r1   ; logical shift right. bit 7 gets 0. C gets original bit 6.
```

Here is what is happening (this one is a bit more complicated, so changes highlighted in green)...

[image]

The above code can be modified for any register R0-R31.

You can read a full description of all these instructions (including the very handy Bit Store instruction on page 46) of the [AVR Instruction Set Manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf).